# Streaming music and videos from url

Tags: blackberry, streaming

I have been searching for a way to stream audio and video for a while. I could find some explanations but not a full tutorial on how to do it. Can anyone please provide a way to do it. Tutorials or sample codes will be very helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [fairly recent blog post](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/05/streaming-player-api/) on the BlackBerry Developer's Blog about the Streaming Media API, including sample code.